# ansible - accessing local environment variables source from file

Tags: bash, ansible

I am calling ansible playbook from shell and in shell before calling playing book i am sourcing environment variables from file

**config.ini:**

```
IPC_IP=1.1.1.1
```

**execute_playbook.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
source /tmp/config.ini
ansible-playbook  myplaybook.yaml
```

**myplaybook.yaml**

```
---
- hosts: "localhost"
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Add Entry to /etc/hosts
      become: yes
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/hosts
        line: "{{ lookup('env','IPC_IP') }}\t\t{{ lookup('env','HOSTNAME') }}"
        state: present
```

Now i can get value of HOSTNAME but not able to get IPC_IP value which i am sourcing from file.

Comment: i would try exporting the variable, in config.ini: `export IPC_IP=1.1.1.1`

Comment: I have 10 variables in file

Comment: Then you need to export them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `source` command, `IPC_IP` is a *shell* variable, but it is not an *environment* variable. You need to export it first.

```
source /tmp/config.ini
export IPC_IP
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yaml
```

Note that `export` applies to *names*, so you can call `export` before `source` as well; once a name is exported, its value can be changed any number of times; the value seen by the child process is the value of the variable at the time the child process begins.

If there are many variables defined in `config.ini` to export, you can temporarily set an option to automatically export any variable that is created or changed while the option is set. For example,

```
set -a
source /tmp/config.ini
set +a
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yaml
```

Finally, be aware that an INI-style file isn't necessarily a shell script, and simply sourcing it may not produce the result you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the shell vs env var concept, this was driving me crazy.